# calling derived class using base class

Tags: c++, class, radix, derived

Below is my code to create a new user or new admin object depending on the boolean isAdmin. The user object is the base object with admin being derived from this. i want to be able to user `user->adminClasshere` like I have with the user functions. I'm not sure how I change it so the user = new Admin creates an admin and not a user.

```
User *user;

if (isAdmin)
{
    user = new Admin();
}
else
{
    user = new User(userLib); //call constructor

}

//User User;
user->loadLibrary();
user->displayLibrary();
```

Comment: `new Admin` already creates an admin. Perhaps you need to read up on virtual functions but it's hard to tell for sure without knowing what exact problem you are facing.

Comment: note that raw new and delete should not be used, read about std::unique_ptr

Comment: Please be clearer as to what "user->adminClasshere" means. Do you wish to access a public data member? Or is this a member function?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up polymorphism with class extension.
In class extension, you can't use a pointer to a base class to work with the extended class like already you found out.
With polymorphism, the derived class has the same interface but with different implementation, so you can just call the function of the base class and it will be dispatched to the function of the actual class when using virtual functions.

The solution is to not do it: if you have an admin user, treat it as a separate kind of user and don't pretend it is just a normal user with some extra features.

Not a solution, but a workaround is to cast the user pointer to the needed type and use the new pointer.  However, use this only when really needed.